# Pass parameter to a stored procedure to crystal report?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2010

I was starting reading this tutorial to utilize crystal reports

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/142064/Step-by-Step-Creation-of-Crystal-Report-using-its

I'm facing this situation, in a stored procedure I have to set some parameters to get the query. So I supposed I need to set the dataSource in runtime, but I have no idea about how to send the stored procedure result to crystal reports and show it in runtime (because until I know, if you want to display something in it, you have to import it and select the fields that you want to place it.

Answer (score 1):

first make new form for crystal viewre.. add crystal viewer in it..

add this code in that form

```
public void ShowForm(DataSet pDataSet)
    {
CrystalDecisions.Shared.ConnectionInfo ConnInfo = new CrystalDecisions.Shared.ConnectionInfo();
ReportDocument RepDoc = new ReportDocument();
RepDoc.Load(ReportPath With Rpt name);

TableLogOnInfo TableLogOnInfo;
        ConnInfo.ServerName = ServerName;
        ConnInfo.DatabaseName = ServerDBName;
        ConnInfo.UserID = ServerDBUserName;
        ConnInfo.Password = ServerDBPassWord;
        foreach (Table TableInRep in RepDoc.Database.Tables)
        {
            TableLogOnInfo = TableInRep.LogOnInfo;
            TableLogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo = ConnInfo;
            TableInRep.ApplyLogOnInfo(TableLogOnInfo);
        }
CryViewer.ReportSource = RepDoc;
RepDoc.Database.Tables[0].SetDataSource(pDataSet);

this.Show();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using CrystalDecisions.Web;
using CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine;
using CrystalDecisions.Shared;

namespace TexERP.ReportCrystal
{
    public partial class AccountRegister : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        clsSession objSession;
        ReportDocument rptDoc;      
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            objSession = new clsSession();         
            rptDoc = new ReportDocument();
            if (Session["objSession"] != null)
            {
                objSession = Session["objSession"] as clsSession;
            }

            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                Session["ReportDataSet"] = null;
            }
            if (Session["ReportDataSet"] != null)
            {
                crvAccountReportParameter.ReportSource = (ReportDocument)Session["ReportDataSet"];
            }
        }


        protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LoadData();         
        }
        protected void LoadData()
        {
            string pstrType;
            pstrType = Request.QueryString["Type"];
            DataSet dsData = null;

            dsData = objAccountReportBAL.getAccountRegister(Convert.ToInt16(objSession.FyId), int.MinValue, long.MinValue, Convert.ToDateTime(RadDtpFromDate.SelectedDate), Convert.ToDateTime(RadDtpToDate.SelectedDate), pstrType);          
            rptDoc.Load(Server.MapPath("~/ReportCrystal/Account/Detail/GeneralVoucharRegister.rpt"));          
            rptDoc.SetDataSource(dsData.Tables[0]);

            Session["ReportDataSet"] = rptDoc;
            crvAccountReportParameter.ReportSource = rptDoc;
            crvAccountReportParameter.DataBind();          
        }
    }
}
```

You can do like this........